# Codeigniter routing errors

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am trying to get a route working, all I get so far is errors.  So far I have:

```
    $route['gig/(:any)/(:any)'] = "gig/details/$1/$2/$3";
```

$1 is a gigcode variable, $2 is the seller and $3 is the title.  I want the url to say gig/seller/title?  How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: I am getting some weird view rendering errors, similar to when I had some routing problems before, so I am guessing there is a problem with the route.  Do you know of a way to do the same route I am asking for using regex?

Comment: `(:any)` is simply replaced with `(.*)` in codeigniter... have you tried putting a `die('test')` at the top of the controller gig/details ? if its getting to the controller its not a route problem.  Also please try to be more specific with your feedback, rather than saying "some wierd view rendering errors" why not actually copy + paste the error you are getting. it will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will require a controller called `gig`, and a method called `details` in the following format:

```
public function details($gig_id, $seller, $title) {

}
```

Also your route is lacking one token, it should be:

```
$route['gig/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "gig/details/$1/$2/$3";
```

to correspond with your URL requirement.